# How to iterate columns while iterating rows?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two CSV tables.

The first one looks like this[image]

The second one like this
[image]

I want to multipy the "Flaechenfaktor" from the first table with the whole timeseries from the second table.

So first I started with this:

```
data_area = pd.read_csv("U:\...\Flaechenfakt_Test.csv",sep=";",header=0)
data_timeseries = pd.read_csv("U:\...\Zeitreihe.csv",sep=";",header=0)

new_data= data_area.Flaechenfaktor[0]*data_timeseries.Coesfeld
```

This works well for the first timeseries from "Coesfeld". For the second one ("Recklinghausen") it would be easy to write it like I have done it with "Coesfeld". But instead of that way I want to iterate the rows in the first table and iterate the columns in the second table, because the table will grow with time. So my question is how can I iterate columns while iterating the rows?

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got the question correctly you can first define the columns you would like to iterate in a list `column_to_iterate` and then

```py
for number_of_column, column in enumerate(columns_to_iterate):
    data_area.loc[number_of_column, 'Flaechenfaktor'] * data_timeseries[column]
```

`number_of_column` will go from 0 to `len(columns_to_iterate) - 1`, so you can browse the rows (if their index is the default integer sequence), while `column` will browse the headers you selected